# Excel Select all items in Listbox Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am stumped I tried the following and for the life of me I cant figure this out....Need to use a comand button on a listbox on an excel vba form.

Iniatilizing the form on load.....it load fine

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
UserForm1.LbNumbers.RowSource = "Sheet2!A1:A3"End Sub
```

Items display in listbox fine

I have a command button under the list box to select all the code

```
Sub CbSelectall_Click()
   For i = 0 To LbNumbers.ListCount - 1
      LbNumbers.Selected(i) = True
   Next i
End Sub
```

If I click on button it jumps to the last line but it doesnt select all the numbers in the listbox. Can someone tell me how can I rectify it to select all the numbers in the listbox.Thank you

Comment: On your listbox, there's a property for `MultiSelect`.  I suspect it is still on the default value of `0 - fmMultiSelectSingle`.  Try changing that property to `2 - fmMultiSelectExtended`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Private Sub lbTraderId_Change()
    If ResetListBox(lbTraderId) Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf lbTraderId.Selected(0) Then
        For i = 1 To lbTraderId.ListCount - 1
            If lbTraderId.Selected(i) = False Then
                lbTraderId.Selected(i) = True
            End If
        Next i
    ElseIf lbTraderId.Selected(0) = False Then
        For i = 1 To lbTraderId.ListCount - 1
            If lbTraderId.Selected(i) = True Then
                lbTraderId.Selected(i) = False
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ResetListBox(lbx As MSForms.ListBox) As Boolean
    Dim x As Long
    Static bExit As Boolean
    If Not bExit Then
        x = lbx.ListIndex
            If x >= 0 And Not lbx Is Me.lbTraderId Then
                bExit = True
                lbx.Selected(x) = Not lbx.Selected(x)
                bExit = False
                ResetListBox = True
            End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Erm....what? While answering this question - you seem to have forgotten to actually answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, my internet was slow

Comment: You should also include an explanation on why your answer solves the OP's original issue - this helps ensure the answer is useful to them and others facing the same problem. Read this article on [answer] for some tips.

Comment: This is very specific code (for your application) which just toggles/resets the selected list of items in a ListBox.  It doesn't answer the OP.